# Infoviz. Calculate tree canvas size prior to drawing

Tags: javascript, hierarchical-data, infovis

On my current project I'm trying to visualize tree structure using Infoviz library to display hierarchical tree structure. It works pretty well and display the tree in the form I want. But the only problem I have is that I do not find a way to draw the tree of random size.

The problem is that I need to draw the full tree with all levels and number of nodes varies according to user data. But infoviz requires canvas of fixed width and height and I didn't find a may to calculate required size prior to drawing. Now infoviz just truncates rest of the tree and there is no way to see it.

The question is: Is it possible to make get canvas size to draw the full tree?

Answer (score 2):

The canvas size is controlled via CSS. You should be able to find it in the base.css file and should look something like this:

```
#infovis {
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

By changing the height and width, you should be able to get the size you need.

Hope that helps!